# Can't read or write files with Tabris.js

Tags: javascript, tabris

I'm on Windows 10, trying to read and write a simple text file using Tabris.js

console.log reports:

```
/local/src/hello.txt
Error: No such file or directory: /local/src/hello.txt
```

CODE:

```
const {fs} = require('tabris');

let path=fs.filesDir + '/src/hello.txt'
console.log(path)

fs.writeFile(path, 'Hello World!', 'ascii')
.then(() => console.log('file written:', path))
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Tabris.js reference:

- https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2017/09/04/tabris-js-2-1-is-here/#extended-file-system-api

#### Clarification:

> If I get this to work, I'm going to do a very simple tutorial.

Tabris runs fine with no issues, but I can't read or write a file because of the error finding the file. I've tried a dozen combinations of things, with dots, no dots etc. - no luck. Tried __directory, fs.filesDir  etc. so path wouldn't be hard coded, nothing working.

**Tabris folders and file location:**

```
C:\Users\Rob Acer Aspire 3\junk\package.json
C:\Users\Rob Acer Aspire 3\junk\src\app.js
```

*Tabris 2.4*

Thanks for all the help.

## UPDATE- got it working...

It seems to work now, with code below.  I was assuming that hello.txt would be in my /src folder, or at least me tabris folder called 'junk' **but** it is writing to another folder. It seems that the docs are correct on this as they say *The path of a directory that the app may use to store persistent files.*

```
  let file = fs.filesDir + '/hello.txt';
  //  ok, this works.. > file written: /local/hello.txt
  // and is located in:
  // C:\Users\Rob Acer Aspire 3\AppData\Local\Packages\EclipseSource.Tabris.js2_en185yn5qwkmw\LocalState\hello.txt
```

I didn't understand what `/local/hello.txt` really meant

So, my question is answered, thanks for help.

Rob

Comment: I posted an answer based on what I can see in your question. If the answer doesn't help, what is the actual directory you are trying to read from in windows form?

Comment: hey thanks.... still now working with the ."./local/src/hello.txt" - actual directory on windows 10 is: C:\Users\Rob Acer Aspire 3\junk\src\hello1.txt  - junk folder was created using ` tabris init`

Comment: That directory would be "./users/Rob Acer Aspire 3/junk/src/hell1.txt" but you should use a relative location to your code so what directory is your code running in?

Comment: I'll add clarification to original question. but I can't get it working with any path... i.e. event this generates error: 
    Error: No such file or directory:
    ./users/Rob Acer Aspire 3/junk/src/hello.txt
 at createError (./node-modules/tabris/tabris.min.js:1:69264)   I've tried different files like hello1.txt, hello.txt etc.

Comment: mrmccormack, Could add this as an answer and mark it as accepted?  That way the question shows up as resolved

Answer (score 0):

On windows

```
"/local/src/hello.txt
```

would be the equivalent of

```
"c:\local\src\hello.txt"
```

In order for the path to start within your application directory, you should star the path with a "./" for current application directory so in your case

```
"./local/src/hello.txt"
```

If you want to go back one directory, you would start with a "../"

Answer (score 0):

It works now, with code below.  I was assuming that hello.txt would be in my /src folder, or at least me tabris folder called 'junk' **but** it is writing to another folder. It seems that the docs are correct on this as they say:

*The path of a directory that the app may use to store persistent files.*

```
  let file = fs.filesDir + '/hello.txt';
  //  ok, this works.. > file written: /local/hello.txt
  // and is located in:
  // C:\Users\Rob Acer Aspire 3\AppData\Local\Packages\EclipseSource.Tabris.js2_en185yn5qwkmw\LocalState\hello.txt
```

I didn't understand what `/local/hello.txt` really meant